# App for taking cropped pictures of pdf

Tags: android, pdf

What are some good apps for taking cropped pictures of pdfs on a tablet device (possibly with a stylus)? My use case is that I want to be able to crop images and paragraphs of from sections of a pdf (as simple rectangle crops in fine) and store them locally in a folder on an android tablet. The pdfs in question are likely many pages (>100) and have a table of contents/bookmarks that apps can take advantage of. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`smartselect`](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/what-is/smart-select/) on my android tablet was sufficient for my use case. Using `xodo` to view the pdf and using `smartselect` to crop section of the pdf (using `xodo` zooming to get desired scale).

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Acrobat Pro XI has a feature built in to export all image assets from a PDF. It depends on whether the PDF is flattened or not (e.g. image objects are squashed sometimes become difficult to extract out)